# Entity Framework error initialization

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a MVC .Net 4.5 project and i have installed Entity Framework.

The version installed was the 6.0.1. But when i run the application, it returns an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of it's
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

So, after i've seen that, i've uninstalled EF, and installed it again, but the 6.0.0 version.
However, the error persist!

Do you know what's the problem?

Thanks people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your app.config or web.config. Maybe here wrong version number. Also check EF library number in references.

Comment: I've already checked that. In the web.config says version 6.0.0 and in the dll too!

Comment: Do you checked PublicKeyToken too? It should be equals between EF.dll in GAC and in your config.

Comment: I've not checked that! How can i do the see the PublicKeyToken in the GAC?

Comment: Sorry EF is not in GAC, it's loaded by Nuget. Do you used Nuget for attaching EF to project?

Comment: Yes, i've installed EF through Nuget!

Comment: In the packages.config i have:
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />

And in the web.config:
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

Comment: Do you have only on project in solution? In you packages folder exists old version of EF?

Comment: No! I have the next architecture (projects):
- DataAccess (with the ef dll. There is the DbContext)
- Entities (poco classes, for codefirst)
- Other projects...

Comment: Ok, remove reference to EF from the all libraries via Nuget. Than again add it. Clear and rebuild project.

Comment: Now it works, but i had to add the entity framework on the client app (the mvc project).
Do you know why? I don't use EF directly because i have a repository on the DataAccess project, so i can't understand why the mvc project need the reference to ef...

Comment: It's a .NET platform basis, dependent libraries should be added as references.

Answer (score 2):

Go to 'Manage NuGet packet for Solution...', click 'Manage' on 'Entity Framework' and check to the projects that require Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to install last version of Entity Framework from NuGet to all of your project in solution.

This worked for me just fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, because I =>
1: created a new solution using the Web API template for VS 2013. This had a reference to EF 5
2: added a new project to solution, to serve as the data layer
3: installed EF to the new project, NuGet installed the latest, EF 6!

The problem was caused because of the version mismatch between projects within the same solution.

The fix was to install EF 6 on the project which had EF 5. NuGet took care to uninstall EF 5.